# Clients cannot send email to me by the reservation form using smptClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, gmail, email-attachments

Im building my first web app with asp.net core and I want the clients to make a reservation for transport , but I cant receive message from them in Gmail.

This is the error from the browser: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZDCc.jpg)

This is my viewModel:

```
namespace CarRental.Web.ViewModels.TransferReservation
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    public class SendTransferInformationViewModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public string NumberOfPersons { get; set; }

        public string FromDestination { get; set; }

        public string ToDestination { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

        public string Time { get; set; }

        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the controller, the * is for privacy:

```
namespace CarRental.Web.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    using CarRental.Web.ViewModels.TransferReservation;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

    public class TransferReservation : BaseController
    {
        public IActionResult ChooseTransfer()
        {
            return this.View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TransferReservationForm(SendTransferInformationViewModel em)
        {
            string name = em.Name;
            string email = em.Email;
            string phoneNumber = em.PhoneNumber;
            string numberOfPersons = em.NumberOfPersons;
            string fromDestination = em.FromDestination;
            string toDestination = em.ToDestination;
            string address = em.Address;
            string date = em.Date;
            string time = em.Time;
            string comment = em.Comment;
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            mm.To.Add("*********imirov96@gmail.com");
            mm.Subject = name;
            mm.Body = phoneNumber;
            mm.Body = numberOfPersons;
            mm.Body = fromDestination;
            mm.Body = toDestination;
            mm.Body = address;
            mm.Body = date;
            mm.Body = time;
            mm.Body = comment;
            mm.From = new MailAddress(email);
            mm.IsBodyHtml = false;
            SmtpClient smpt = new SmtpClient("smpt.gmail.com");
            smpt.Port = 587;
            smpt.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smpt.EnableSsl = true;
            smpt.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*********mirov96@gmail.com", "********");
            smpt.Send(mm);
            this.ViewBag.message = "The Mail Has Been Sent To ElisCar Successfully ! We will contact you a few minutes later !";
            return this.View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view, where I make all the labels for Name,Phone, Date and etc:

```
@using CarRental.Common
@model CarRental.Web.ViewModels.TransferReservation.SendTransferInformationViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <h2 style="text-align: left;">Contact with us</h2>
    <p>If you are interested in routes that are not described in the price list, other questions or to book a transfer, do not hesitate to contact us by phone <b>+359 893997896</b> or by filling out the contact form.</p>
    <form asp-action="TransferReservationForm">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="Name"><b>Name:</b></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="Email"><b>Email:</b></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" type="email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="PhoneNumber"><b>Phone Number:</b></label>
                <input asp-for="PhoneNumber" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="NumberOfPersons"><b>Number of persons:</b></label>
                <select asp-items="new List<SelectListItem>()" class="form-control">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                    <option>6</option>
                    <option>7</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FromDestination"><b>From: Destination</b></label>
            <select asp-items="new List<SelectListItem>()" class="form-control">
                <option selected>Airport Varna</option>
                <option>Airport Bourgas</option>
                <option>Albena</option>
                <option>Balchik</option>
                <option>Bucuresti(Romania)</option>
                <option>Bourgas</option>
                <option>Bliznatsi</option>
                <option>Byala</option>
                <option>Costinesti(Romania)</option>
                <option>Constanta(Romania)</option>
                <option>Chernomorets</option>
                <option>Dobrich</option>
                <option>Devnya</option>
                <option>Golden Sands</option>
                <option>Kranevo</option>
                <option>Kavarna</option>
                <option>Kiten</option>
                <option>Lighthouse Golf & Spa Resort</option>
                <option>Mangalia(Romania)</option>
                <option>Nesebar</option>
                <option>Obzor</option>
                <option>Plovdiv</option>
                <option>Pomorie</option>
                <option>Primorsko</option>
                <option>Ravda</option>
                <option>Ruse</option>
                <option>Sv.Constantin and Elena</option>
                <option>Shabla</option>
                <option>Shumen</option>
                <option>Sofia</option>
                <option>Shkorpilovtsi</option>
                <option>Sunny Beach</option>
                <option>Sveti Vlas</option>
                <option>Sozopol</option>
                <option>Varna Center</option>
                <option>Veliko Tarnovo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ToDestination"><b>To: Destination</b></label>
            <select asp-items="new List<SelectListItem>()" class="form-control">
                <option>Airport Varna</option>
                <option>Airport Bourgas</option>
                <option>Albena</option>
                <option>Balchik</option>
                <option>Bucuresti(Romania)</option>
                <option>Bourgas</option>
                <option>Bliznatsi</option>
                <option>Byala</option>
                <option>Costinesti(Romania)</option>
                <option>Constanta(Romania)</option>
                <option>Chernomorets</option>
                <option>Dobrich</option>
                <option>Devnya</option>
                <option>Golden Sands</option>
                <option>Kranevo</option>
                <option>Kavarna</option>
                <option>Kiten</option>
                <option>Lighthouse Golf & Spa Resort</option>
                <option>Mangalia(Romania)</option>
                <option>Nesebar</option>
                <option>Obzor</option>
                <option>Plovdiv</option>
                <option>Pomorie</option>
                <option>Primorsko</option>
                <option>Ravda</option>
                <option>Ruse</option>
                <option>Sv.Constantin and Elena</option>
                <option>Shabla</option>
                <option>Shumen</option>
                <option>Sofia</option>
                <option>Shkorpilovtsi</option>
                <option>Sunny Beach</option>
                <option>Sveti Vlas</option>
                <option>Sozopol</option>
                <option>Varna Center</option>
                <option>Veliko Tarnovo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label asp-for="Address"><b>Address/Hotel/Flight Number</b></label>
                <input asp-for="Address" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your information about the pick up" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="Date"><b>Date</b></label>
                <input asp-for="Date" type="date" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                <label asp-for="Time"><b>Time</b></label>
                <input asp-for="Time" type="time" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Comment"><b>Comment:</b></label>
                <textarea asp-for="Comment" type="text" class="form-control" rows="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        <h3>@ViewBag.message</h3>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe the port for SSL is 465 TLS is 587

Comment: Still the same error :(

Comment: "smpt.gmail.com" should be "smtp.gmail.com"

Comment: Yeah , and I made a change on my gmail account. I was blocked by the authorization system. Thanks !